# How to determine which subview clicked and set action to it in UIStackview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, rx-swift, uistackview

I am trying to navigate to a specific screen depending on the subview clicked in a UIStackView. How do I set tap gesture to the view and know which subview I actually tapped on?

**ViewModel.swift**

```
    let currentAccount = UIAccountCardView(accountType: "Account 1",
                                           accountNumber: "",
                                           accountBalance: "")

    let savingsAccount = UIAccountCardView(accountType: "Account 2",
                                           accountNumber: "",
                                           accountBalance: "")

    let basicSavingsAccount = UIAccountCardView(accountType: "Account 3",
                                                accountNumber: "",
                                                accountBalance: "")

    let accounts = [currentAccount, savingsAccount, basicSavingsAccount]

    let accountCards = Observable.just(accounts)
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
viewModel.output.accountCards
            .subscribe(onNext: { accounts in
                accounts.forEach({ [weak self] cardView in
                    // Set tap gesture recognizer here?
                    // How do I know which cardView did I tap on?
                    self?.dashboardView.accountStackView.addArrangedSubview(cardView)
                })
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want to add a tap gesture recognizer to all of the `cardViews`. Add this to your `accounts.forEach`:

```
// Make sure we're using strong reference to self.
guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
// Add arranged subview.
strongSelf.dashboardView.accountStackView.addArrangedSubview(cardView)
// Add tap recognizer.
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: strongSelf, action: #selector(strongSelf.accountWasSelected(_:))
cardView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
// Not typically necessary, but just in case you could set:
cardView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Then, make an action `func` for the selector, and check which account/cardView instance called it.

```
@objc func accountWasSelected(_ account: UIAccountCardView) {
    if account == savingsAccount {
        // Do stuff with savings.
    } else if account == currentAccount {
        // Do stuff with current.
    } else if account == basicSavingsAccount {
        // Do stuff with basic
    }
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: So by setting target self, it will crash the app when I tap on the cardView. I suppose it should be setting cardView as the target. The odd part is if I replace #selector(accountWasSelected(_:)) with #selector(handleTap) and handleTap is a just an empty objc method {@objc private func handleTap() { } }, it will work and that is really odd, otherwise it will crash as well, with error "unrecognized selector sent to instance".

Comment: No, the `target` should be the object that contains the `action` - `accountWasSelected` (which should be defined in your parent `ViewController`). **Edited the above code - forgot that you'd need a strong reference to self for target**

Comment: The method `accountWasSelected` requires explicit self as well. After I added `strongSelf.accountWasSelected(:_)`, when I tapped on the card to print the label text, it returns **nil** and also if I tap fast, it will crash the app with the same error "unrecognized selector sent to instance"